# backbone model with an array/object property: infinite 'change' event triggered after sync()?

Tags: backbone.js

My backbone.js model has an array property.  I bound the `change` event to `save()`.

After `sync()` (triggered by `save()`, my app server returns an identical JSON, but backbone thinks the array has been changed (due to a different reference to the array I guess?), and trigger changes again.  Then an infinite loop occurs.

```
save() -> sync() -> triggered `change` -> save()...
```

What shall I do?

Idea: I can bind the change event to a function that checks if the changed attributes are of type object/array, and do a deep comparison and call save only if the array/object really changed.  If true then `save()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Edge version of Backbone (master branch) this behavior changed after 0.9.9 - see https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/2004

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has a special option on many methods to prevent just this sort of issue: `silent:true`.  If you pass that option to your `save` method, the resulting `sync` won't trigger a change event.

So, if you want to set your change event handler to save silently, something like:

```
changeHandler: function() {
    this.save({silent:true});
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I actually want the change event triggered so I can assign property like 'id' back to the backbone model on save.  So it'd be better if I can somehow make backbone do a deep compare of the object/array if possible?

Comment: Backbone uses an internal `changed` property to track whether a model has changed or not (and specifically, which attributes have changed), and then it uses a `hasChanged` method to check that property.  You could certainly override `hasChanged` to make it work however you want.

Comment: I've tracked down to the `_computeChanges()` method where it uses a simple `!==` instead of underscore's `isEqual()` for array/object. I wonder if it's safe to override `_computeChanges()` for my use case.

Comment: If a method name starts with `_` in Javascript, that generally means it is a *private* method, and therefore not safe for you to override.  `hasChanged` is not private though, and thus is (comparatively) safe to overwrite.